# Recommendations for statistical models given my dataset

Tags: machine-learning, r, random-forest, cross-validation

I'm having a problem when using the k-fold cross-validation with the Random Forest method. One of the outputs is the error "Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = param$mtry, ...) : Need at least two classes to do classification." However, I already have two classes to do the classification, which are "Normal" and "Failure". When posting this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60643415/error-in-randomforest-defaultx-y-mtry-parammtry-need-at-least-two?noredirect=1#comment107290940_60643415 was recommended to me that I ask for "recommendations for statistical models given my data and your prediction/estimation/modeling needs".

Someone could help me?

The R script:

```
library(caret)    
library(randomForest)

data_failures <- read.csv('OUTPUT.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
model <- train(Period_1 ~., data = data_failures, method = "rf",
                                   trControl = train.control)
print(model)

print(class(str(data_failures)))
```

The ouput:

```
Random Forest

112 samples
 11 predictor
  2 classes: 'Failure', 'Normal'

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold)
Summary of sample sizes: 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, ...
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  Accuracy  Kappa
   2    1         NaN
   6    1         NaN
  11    1         NaN

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 2.
'data.frame':   112 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ Period_1 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_2 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ Period_3 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_4 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_5 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_6 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_7 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_8 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_9 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_10: Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_11: Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Period_12: Factor w/ 2 levels "Failure","Normal": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
[1] "NULL"
Warning messages:
1: model fit failed for Fold08: mtry= 2 Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = param$mtry, ...) :
  Need at least two classes to do classification.

2: model fit failed for Fold08: mtry= 6 Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = param$mtry, ...) :
  Need at least two classes to do classification.

3: model fit failed for Fold08: mtry=11 Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = param$mtry, ...) :
  Need at least two classes to do classification.

4: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

A sample of the data:

````
    Period_1 Period_2 Period_3 Period_4 Period_5 Period_6 Period_7 Period_8
1     Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
2     Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
3     Normal   Normal  Failure   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
4     Normal  Failure   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal  Failure
5     Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
6     Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
7     Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
8     Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
9     Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
10    Normal  Failure   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal   Normal
```
````

Comment: So what are you trying to predict exactly ? From your code you seems to try to predict what happen in period 1, from other periods. Is that your goal ?

Comment: As Vincent said, not enough failure cases causes a random CV subset to contain 0 "failure" instances. You can also try to reduce the 'k' in k-fold btw.

Comment: @lcrmorin Exactly, I'm trying to predict what happens in the Period 1 from other periods. I want the accuracy of the model when predicting such results...

Comment: @Erwan I've tried to reduce the "k" folds but it didn't work. The warning was: `Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that either your Failure/Normal class is a lot lesser than the other. As such, for a certain (i.e. nth) fold, there only exists instances of one class. You can try doing oversampling the under-represented class to prevent this, or try doing a stratified K-Fold so that each fold will have occurrences of both classes.

Comment: I've tried to use the stratified k-fold, however, the output warning was: `Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.`